# starting a python Http server from Java

Tags: python, java, http

I am trying to start a Http server writing in python through my java code. Initially it seems to work fine, but after 8 requests it closes again. What am I doing wrong?
the server is started like this:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("python", "src\\main\\java\\python\\HttpHandler.py");
Process p = builder.start();
```

and within the python code the server looks like this:

```
class HttpHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_GET(self):
        #handle get request

    def do_POST(self):
        #handle post request

with HTTPServer(('', 8000), HttpHandler) as server:
    server.serve_forever()
```

Comment: Does your Java code keep running? If not, the processes would be closed together

Comment: My best guess is that the server is writing output to its standard output or standard error streams, but you're not reading either of them, and so eventually a buffer fills up and the server process blocks because it can't write any more.

Comment: @OneCricketeer the java code keeps running

Comment: @LukeWoodward yes this turned out to be the issue. overiding the http log function fixed it. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, the problem was caused by the server process writing to its standard output or standard error streams, and the Java code not reading from these streams.  Eventually a buffer filled up and the server process blocked because it couldn't write to the buffer.  Overriding the http log function fixed the problem.